# Excel formulas replaced with values sporadically after using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro for Excel to populate data from one internal file to an external monthly report. As is, 90-95% of the time, it works perfectly. However, I have found that occasionally, it appears to turn the equations in the original file into values, which then forces me to have to fix all of the equations before I run the next month's report.

The code (below) works by running from the internal report and opening the most recent external report (or one selected by the user). In both reports, there are matching named ranges. The macro then iterates through the named ranges and sets the external report's ranges to equal the value of the internal report's ranges.

Currently, I populate client reports from nearly identical internal reports about 15 times a month, and despite all of my best efforts, I cannot appear to replicate the problem. It just seems to do it sometimes and not others. I usually do not even find out that the original formulas are gone until the following month (though, now I am paying more attention to the potential problem).

I read that if Excel copies a range from one instance of Excel to another, it can cause the original equations to be [set to values](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/excel-l/formulas-disappeared-in-excel-file-4665988), but I do not believe that my code should be creating separate instances of Excel, and when I added a code to try to warn me when a second instance was started, it did not seem to address the problem. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or does anyone have any idea of what might be going on (either in how to reproduce or to fix it?).

Thank you for you help.

FYI: I am running Excel 2010 on Windows 7. Also, the files are hosted on a shared drive, and therefore are not running of my local machine.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wbSeoReport As Workbook 'Internal workbook
Dim wbClientReport As Workbook 'workbook for clients
Dim sSeoReportName As String
Dim sClientFileName As String 'wbClientReport Name
Dim sFilePath As String 'Folder containing this file

Sub Populate_Client_File()

Dim replace_page As Worksheet
Dim sCompanyName As String 'Client company name
Dim sClientFileNameAndPath As String 'wbClientReport Name and path for opening file
'These are used to find the most recent version (date is this month or last, version is the highest available, starting at 10)
Dim iClientFileMonth As Integer
Dim iOriginalMonth As Integer
Dim iClientFileYear As Integer
Dim iClientFileVersion As Integer
Dim sClientFileVersion As String 'this is used to add the v to the client version as iClientFileVersion iterates from 10-1
Dim objFileDialog As FileDialog 'This is for selecting a file when the user does not want the most recent
Dim iUserInput As Integer 'Used to decide whether the most recent file will be used or not.
Dim bFileExists As Boolean
Dim bStayInLoop As Boolean
Dim x As Long, z As Long
Dim labels(1 To 1000) As String

Set wbSeoReport = ThisWorkbook

If ExcelInstances > 1 Then 'This checks the instances of Excel, which could be an issue making formulas saving as values.
    MsgBox "There are " & str(ExcelInstances) & " instances of Excel open. Please close extra instances and start again."
    Exit Sub
End If

sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"

iUserInput = MsgBox("Would you like to use the most recent file?", vbYesNoCancel) 'Results returned as integers: 6 is yes, 7 is no, 2 is cancel

If iUserInput = 6 Then
'The following code seeks to identify the most recent client file based on month and file version
'it then checks if it is open, opens it, and sets the file as wbClientReport

    iClientFileMonth = Month(wbSeoReport.Worksheets("Traffic Summary").range("S1").value)
    iOriginalMonth = iClientFileMonth 'This is used for only running the file finder once.
    iClientFileYear = Year(wbSeoReport.Worksheets("Traffic Summary").range("S1").value) - 2000
    sCompanyName = wbSeoReport.Worksheets("Traffic Summary").range("Z1").value
    bFileExists = False

     bStayInLoop = True
     'This loop is used to go through this month and the previous.
     'If it fails, you can select the report to open.
        Do While bStayInLoop = True

                For iClientFileVersion = 10 To 0 Step -1
                'This loops through file versions starting at 10.
                    If iClientFileVersion > 0 Then
                        sClientFileVersion = " v" & iClientFileVersion
                    Else
                        sClientFileVersion = ""
                    End If
                    sClientFileNameAndPath = sFilePath & sCompanyName & " - MOM -  Client Report  " & iClientFileYear & " - " & iClientFileMonth _
                    & sClientFileVersion & ".xlsm"
                    sClientFileName = sCompanyName & " - MOM -  Client Report  " & iClientFileYear & " - " & iClientFileMonth _
                    & sClientFileVersion & ".xlsm"
                    bFileExists = IsFile(sClientFileNameAndPath)
                    If bFileExists = True Then
                        bStayInLoop = False
                        Exit For
                        'GoTo exitLoop
                    End If
                Next iClientFileVersion

                If bStayInLoop = True Then

                    If iOriginalMonth - 1 = 0 And iClientFileMonth - 1 = 0 Then
                        iClientFileMonth = 12
                        iClientFileYear = iClientFileYear - 1
                    ElseIf iClientFileMonth = iOriginalMonth Then
                        iClientFileMonth = iClientFileMonth - 1
                    Else
                        iUserInput = 7 'Allows user to find file.
                        bStayInLoop = False
                    End If
                End If

        Loop

        'This sets an opened file (or opens it) to the wbClientReport
        If bFileExists = True Then
            If BookOpen(sClientFileName) = True Then
                Set wbClientReport = Workbooks(sClientFileName)
            Else
                Set wbClientReport = Workbooks.Open(sClientFileNameAndPath)
            End If
        End If
End If
If iUserInput = 7 Then
'This allows a user to select their own file.
    Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With objFileDialog
        .InitialFileName = sFilePath
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
         sClientFileName = Dir(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
        .Execute
    End With
'This sets an opened file (or opens it) to the wbClientReport
    Set wbClientReport = Workbooks(sClientFileName)
ElseIf iUserInput = 6 Then
    'Do nothing. Work has already been done.
Else
    'User pressed cancel
    GoTo EndOfCode
End If

sSeoReportName = wbSeoReport.name

If ExcelInstances > 1 Then 'This checks the instances of Excel, which could be an issue making formulas saving as values.
    MsgBox "There are " & str(ExcelInstances) & " instances of Excel open. Please close extra instances and start again."
    Exit Sub
End If

'This code calls the function that sets the named ranges equal to each other to populate
'the data from the SEO Report to the Client Report

Populate_Client_Template

'This makes errors = 0 to look better for clients.
For Each replace_page In wbClientReport.Worksheets

        replace_page.Cells.Replace what:="#DIV/0!", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next
EndOfCode:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Populate_Client_Template()
Dim replace_page As Worksheet
Dim label As String 'Used to identify one label in a named range.
Dim labels(1 To 1000) As String 'Used to store all of the named range labels.
Dim x As Long, z As Long 'x keeps track of the entry number in labels. z is a loop iterator.
Dim rngTitleRange As range

x = 0

labels(x + 1) = "Branded_Keywords"
x = x + 1
labels(x + 1) = "Conversion_Rate_by_Source"
x = x + 1
'...
'This adds about 30 more names of the named ranges to the array "labels" to be iterated through in the following loop.

On Error Resume Next

For z = 1 To x + 1
    Fill_Client_Report (labels(z)) 'Uses function to populate Client Report with data.
    Fill_Client_Report (labels(z) & "_Titles") 'Uses function to populate named ranges that have title info (ie column a in 13 month window).
Next z

End Sub

Sub Fill_Client_Report(label As String)

Dim wsClient_Page As Worksheet 'This is used to select the page on which a named range exists in the client report
Dim wsSeo_Page As Worksheet 'This is used to select the page on which a named range exists in the SEO Report
Dim rngTestRange As range 'This is used to check if a named range exists in the respective documents.


wbSeoReport.Activate
On Error Resume Next
Set rngTestRange = range(label)
If Not rngTestRange Is Nothing Then 'This checks if the named range exists in the SEO Report
    Set wsSeo_Page = range(label).parent 'This sets the page containing the named range.
    wbClientReport.Activate
    Set rngTestRange = range(label)
    If Not rngTestRange Is Nothing Then 'This checks if the named range exists in the Client Report
        Set wsClient_Page = range(label).parent 'This sets the page containing the named range.
    'The following sets the two ranges equal to populate the client report with seo report data.
        wsClient_Page.range(label).value = wsSeo_Page.range(label).value
    Else
        'This shows is the named range isn't in the client report.
        Debug.Print label
    End If
Else
    'This shows if the named range isn't in the seo report.
    Debug.Print label
End If

End Sub

Function IsFile(fName As String) As Boolean
    'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file.
    'Returns FALSE if not existing, or if it's a folder
        On Error Resume Next
        IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function


Function BookOpen(strBookName As String) As Boolean
    'This code checks if a workbook is open
    Dim Bk As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Bk = Workbooks(strBookName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Bk Is Nothing Then
        BookOpen = False
    Else
        BookOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Your code is too long to really get a sense of the core of the problem, plus it's filled with `On Error Resume Next` which doesn't help...  I see some unqualified `Range()` calls in `Fill_Client_Report` - you should try to never use that form - always qualify with a worksheet object or your code may behave unpredictably.  That may well be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Do you have a sense of *when* the errors happen? Stepping through the macro may help (use `F8`), or you can also set a Watch, to look out for a change to some variable.  I'd start by commenting out the `On Error Resume` so any errors get brought to your attention (as perhaps one of these errors is causing your issue).

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I do not know when the error happens because it only happens about 1 in every 30 times I run it. I've tried re-running the code on a file that had the problem in several ways (with the external report open, with it closed, with selecting the file, with Bruce:having the newest one chosen, etc.) and not been able to reproduce it. I did not know about Watch. I think that could be the way to keep an eye out for this. A lot of the On Error Resume Next calls are because each file is slightly different (different named ranges), so I don't think I would get far without those.

Comment: Tim, I agree that unqualified Range() calls are not ideal, but those are set up to identify to correct page hosting the named range (there are usually two matching named ranges, but they may be on different pages across reports). My approach works around this, but I might need to make sure that the workbooks don't get swapped when it does this. I'll look into this.

Comment: You could add in a section of code which continually checks whether a certain cell has a value or a formula. Then add a watch to it, and go about your business as you have been. When you run it and it creates the error, the code will pause, and you should have some more info about what was going on when it happened. As it stands, your question is basically "This is way too tedious for me to debug because it doesnt happen all the time. Does someone else want to debug it for me?" Not a lot we can say without actually having your data and just running it, as you should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code more robust by using a function to get the named ranges which takes both a workbook argument and a range name.

E.g:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = GetNamedRange(ActiveWorkbook, "TESTER2")
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print rng.Parent.Name, rng.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "Range not found!"
    End If
End Sub

'returns the range for "theName", or Nothing if not found
Function GetNamedRange(wb As Workbook, theName As String)
    Dim rv As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore a specific error
    Set rv = ActiveWorkbook.Names("TESTER2").RefersToRange
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    Set GetNamedRange = rv
End Function
```

Where possible you should remove `On Error Resume Next` from the rest of your code: if you *have* to use it then make sure you turn it off again as soon as possible.

It's OK to ignore specific errors if you can reasonably expect that they might occur in *normal* operation and you can test for the error after the case, but you shouldn't ignore errors wholesale.

Comment: Thanks. For the input on using `On Error GoTo 0` to limit the scope of `On Error Resume Next`. That will help with debugging. Also, this function is a much better way to identify matching ranges in the "Fill_Client_Report" part of my code. I'll roll it out across my reports and see if that along with a function watching for the problem helps me find the error.

Comment: After incorporating this function into my code and testing it out for several months, the problem appears to have gone away. I think using the `Workbook.Names("Name_of_Named_Range").RefersToRange` accomplished what I had been attempting to do in my earlier code, but it allowed me to have more control over the workbook so that it didn't get mixed up and overwrite my range with values. Thank you very much for your help!